# STMCubeIDE Debugging Live Expressions

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I have a Live Expressions problem on STMCubeIDE. My problem is I can not see my variable on Live Expression. I am trying to calculet voltage and that is why i am using adc with dma. I have one adc_val[3] array and i can see arrays variable thet i calculeted but i can not see my calculeted voltage variable as you can see on picture.

[define of the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnOsP.png)

[Convert that i measured value to mV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7aD2.png)

My question is, how is it possible to se adc_mV1, adc_mV2, adc_mV3 to see on live expression?

```html
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */


/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
    uint32_t adc_val [3];
    float adc_mV1=0;
    float adc_mV2=0;
    float adc_mV3=0;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1,(uint32_t *)adc_val,3);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(led_red_GPIO_Port,led_red_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(1);
      adc_mV1= (3300/4096)*adc_val[0];
      adc_mV2 = (3300/4096)*adc_val[1];
      adc_mV3 = (3300/4096)*adc_val[3];
      HAL_Delay(100);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCPCLK2_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 3;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_55CYCLES_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 1 */
  huart3.Instance = USART3;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, led_green_Pin|led_red_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : led_green_Pin led_red_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = led_green_Pin|led_red_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Hello, I don't really understand your problem, on your pictures your variables are here.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem ist **not** the live expressions but your C code.

```
adc_mV1 = (3300/4096)*adc_val[0];
```

This is always 0.

`(3300/4096)` will be executed as integer division and the result is zero, so your voltages will also always be zero.

To avoid float calculations you could use:

```
adc_mV1= (3300*adc_val[0]) / 4096;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood the problem clearly.